# remove repeated people from array, leaving only one comment from the same people

Tags: javascript, arrays

Example

```
commentsArray = ["John?mycomment284","Sophie?mycomment938","John?mycomment595"]
```

Result: `commentsArray = ["John?mycomment284","Sophie?mycomment938"]`

all comments are separated from the name by the "?"

how to leave only one comment per person? and removes all others from the same person.

Comment: Can you add to your question the intended result, and what you have tried so far ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please can you state what you have attempted yourself? Stack Overflow is not designed for us to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter:

```js
const commentsArray = ["John?mycomment284","Sophie?mycomment938","John?mycomment595"]
let people=[];
let firstComment = commentsArray.filter(comment => { 
      let person = comment.split("?")[0];
      if (people.indexOf(person) ==-1) {
        people.push(person);
        return comment;
      }  
    });
console.log(
  firstComment
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const commentsArray = ["John?mycomment284","Sophie?mycomment938","John?mycomment595"]

const res = Object.values(commentsArray.reduce((acc, cur) => acc[cur.split('?')[0]] ? acc : (acc[cur.split('?')[0]] = cur, acc), {}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: There are three comments, your solution loses one.

Comment: that's the requirement

Comment: Using filter and searching the result array on each iteration is potentially O(n**2) @mplungjan, this is O(n)

Comment: I am sure I would consider it if there were thousands of messages :)